# Reviewing two things at once

Tags: rules, cricket

In international cricket if an umpire gives a batsman not out after an appeal by the fielding side then the captain of the fielding side can review the decision.

Scenario: A batsman gets a tiny edge onto his pad and the fielding side appeals for lbw while the ball bounces up to a fielder who catches it. The umpire gives it not out. The captain is unsure whether the batsman has hit it but reviews the lbw anyway. The edge comes up on hot-spot so it can't be lbw.

> Can a team review two things at once so the third umpire could give him caught out in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cricket an appeal covers all forms of dismissal, so even if the bowler appeals for LBW, the umpire can give the batsman out caught if he's happy the conditions for that dismissal have been met. ([Law 27 section 4](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-27-appeals/))

In the same fashion, one review will cover all forms of dismissal. The [Third Umpire - Decision Review System](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/518a6f5d5f88e-Third%20Umpire%20-%20Decision%20Review%20System.pdf) rules explicitly state this in section 3.3 point f:

> The third umpire shall not withhold any factual information which may help in the
>   decision making process, even if the information is not directly prompted by the
>   on-field umpire’s questions. In particular, in reviewing a dismissal, if the third
>   umpire believes that the batsman may instead be out by any other mode of
>   dismissal, he shall advise the on-field umpire accordingly. The process of
>   consultation described in this paragraph in respect of such other mode of dismissal
>   shall then be conducted as if the batsman has been given not out.